# esp32 showing up as AAP server instead of CP210N USB to UART bridge controller

Tags: driver, esp32

I am trying to run my first program using the esp32wroom module. But my laptop is not recognizing the esp32. I tried it on my desktop and it showed up as CP210N USB to UART bridge controller.

I have installed the drivers.
[image: Device Manager]

Thanks for the help in advance!